# Can you switch from an Elastic IP address to a pooled public IP on an EC2 in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, elastic-ip

I currently have a legacy instance that had an Elastic IP address assigned to it.

I have moved this instance to a VPC in a public subnet, and no longer need the Elastic IP address on it. If I remove the Elastic IP address, will it start getting a public IP address from the AWS pool?

I really do -not- want to pull the EIP and then have this box's traffic have nowhere to go. We have DNS resolution set up on the box to automatically map the machine's Route53 DNS information when it gets a new IP address, but that only works -if- it gets the new IP from AWS.

Can this be done without terminating and relaunching the instance? If it is a matter of just disassociating the Elastic IP for it to get the new one - great, otherwise it's going to be more involved. I do have a VPC with private and public subnets, would they play a role in it? We are not using any DHCP or anything.

Comment: It feels like there might be a need to challenge the premise of the question.  You have a running server with an EIP attached, and if the instance isn't stopped, then you aren't paying anything for that EIP... and AWS Support will give you more EIPs if you are at quota for the region, so why the need to remove the EIP?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - well, it is not necessary for the EIP because I can just set up the DNS entry in Route53 automatically when the box boots. I can access the box via hostname instead of elastic IP